# Long dropdown menu not a list - How to make it scroll?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to implement what I read on [this site](https://css-tricks.com/long-dropdowns-solution/) and in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j5kyk7a3/) but I really can't understand how to make it work.

This is my menu. I changed the class on the code to the class of my menu but it didn't work. I don't have a list type menu as well.

```html
<div class="NAV" id="CARDMENU">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">
      Card
      <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">card</a>
      <a href="#">card</a>
      <a href="#">card</a>
      <a href="#">card</a>
      <a href="#">card</a>
      <a href="#">card</a>
      <a href="#">card</a>
      <a href="#">card</a>
      <a href="#">card</a>
      <a href="#">card</a>
      <a href="#">card</a>
      <a href="#">card</a>
      <a href="#">card</a>
      <a href="#">card</a>
      <a href="#">card</a>
      <a href="#">card</a>
      <a href="#">card</a>
      <a href="#">card</a>
      <a href="#">card</a>
      <a href="#">card</a>
      <a href="#">card</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I just like to have some guiding words sir..

Comment: Start with w3schools :D

Comment: @StupidKid No, start with MDN. W3Schools should be avoided as it's often outdated and sometimes just plain wrong. Bad advice is worse than no advice.

Comment: In his option he can learn it from any website on web with tutorials :D

Answer (score 2):

```
.dropdown-content{
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```